# Sorting data in table angular 2

Tags: angular

How to implemenet sorting data in table with angular 2? With pipe? For example table 5 x 5, click on first cell (on button maybe), and sort all column.

Comment: Do you want to implement it yourself or using other modules? loot at this: http://valor-software.com/ng2-table

Answer (score 2):

The Angular team has advised that you don't use filter pipes in Angular2, as it is an extremely expensive operation.

> "The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend that you move filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component."

Now that Angular apps are component based, it is even easier to take this approach when trying to implement any client-side logic that could crush your app's overall performance.

Check out https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe for more info.