# How to do sorting table column in Angular2 / Angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

how to sorting table column name in angular2/ angular4.i tried so many refernce link.but couldn't get execute properly.kindly give any reference link for angular2/ angular4

Comment: do some google, or put something here what have you done or tried for it. simple asking for a solution is not a good way to ask the question, please check how to ask link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: actually im doing employee leave management application by suing angular2 for front end and dotnet(c#) for backend.in that app employee will ask leave to manager and gets approval.so in emp dashboard should shows histry of leaves .by the way emp can sorting the leave histry table by sort by or order by.so genius can help here

Answer (score 0):

[here is a plunker you can see it] (http://embed.plnkr.co/4eXHag)
[another](https://long2know.com/2017/04/angular-custom-table-component-sorting/) 
[and ...] ([Sorting data in table angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160369/sorting-data-in-table-angular-2)) 
[and the last one] ([angular 2 sort and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882013/angular-2-sort-and-filter))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular encourages to use pipes to sort columns of a table. Instead the sorting mechanism needs to stay within the component itself.